# Completely loading JFrame before opening a new

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm have a fully functional GUI that starts up a connection to a connected USB device. That start up procedure takes somewhere around 3 seconds. During that time I want to show a splash-screen to the user that tells him/her that the program is starting. I've created a "SplashFrame" class (extension of JFrame) that creates a panel with two labels and puts them on the frame.

I do however have the problem that the SplashFrame only fully loads once the setup procedure for the other "main" frame is done. And this means that neither of the labels are readable before I intentionally close the SplashFrame. How do I "force" the SplashFrame to fully load before starting the main frame?

This is my main method

```
private static JFrame frame;
private static SplashFrame splash;

public static void main(String[] args){

  SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Turn off metal's use of bold fonts
            UIManager.put("swing.boldMetal", Boolean.FALSE);

            splash = new SplashFrame();
            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            frame = new CFSMainFrame();
            long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long totalTime = endTime - startTime;
            System.out.println("Total time: " + ((float)totalTime/1000) + " seconds!");
            splash.closeFrame();
        }
    });
}
```

and this is my splashFrame

```
public class SplashFrame extends JFrame{

private static JFrame frame;

public SplashFrame(){
    frame = new JFrame("Loading...");
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    frame.setSize(300, 150);

    ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("resources/mini_logo.png");
    frame.setIconImage(img.getImage());

    JPanel pane = splashPanel();
    frame.add(pane);
    createAndShowGUI();
}

private JPanel splashPanel(){
    JPanel pane = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

    ImageIcon loadingImg = new ImageIcon("resources/logo.png");
    JLabel imageLabel = new JLabel();
    imageLabel.setIcon(loadingImg);

    JLabel loadingLabel = new JLabel("Loading");

    loadingLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    loadingLabel.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    loadingLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 165));

    pane.add(imageLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    pane.add(loadingLabel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

    return pane;
}

private void createAndShowGUI(){
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}

public void closeFrame(){
    frame.setVisible(false);
    frame.dispose();
}
```

Comment: [Oracle tutorial: How to Create a Splash Screen](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/splashscreen.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking through a huge amount of tutorials using Netbeans (I'm using eclipse myself) I tried doing a couple of different things with my code. One thing I noticed was that in all the tutorials the "splash" demo wasn't run through a Thread. So I tried moving the SplashFrame initialization out of the thread. And that did the trick.

```
private static JFrame frame;
private static SplashFrame splash;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            
    UIManager.put("swing.boldMetal", Boolean.FALSE);
    splash = new SplashFrame();
    
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(4500); //Extending time to show the splash screen
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            
            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            frame = new CFSMainFrame();
            long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long totalTime = endTime - startTime;
            System.out.println("Total time: " + ((float)totalTime/1000) + " seconds!");
            splash.closeFrame();

        }
    });
}
```

Firstly I had the splash.closeFrame() method before the initialization of the main frame, however this didn't work. I noticed the code "timing" code reported the set up time and put the closeFrame() method call down there and it worked as I intended it to.

## EDIT

I found that doing this the interface remains static and cannot be changed because it doesn't run a thread for updating the interface or anything alike. I wanted to put a gif image showing a rotating loading icon on the SplashFrame so it wasn't very suitable.

So I ended up changing the approach to this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    
    UIManager.put("swing.boldMetal", Boolean.FALSE);
    
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            splash = new SplashFrame();
            
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    frame = new CFSMainFrame();
                    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    long totalTime = endTime - startTime;
                    System.out.println("Total time: " + ((float)totalTime/1000) + " seconds!");
                    splash.closeFrame();
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

I'm not saying this is the best optimized way of achieving this, but it gave me the results I wanted/needed.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you seperate your USB connection logic from your UI. This would allow you to use the main Thread for your logical flow show Splashscreen, then start connecting via USB and if connected show Application screen.
Just a rough example what it could look like:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final SplashFrame splash = new SplashFrame();
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            splash.pack();
            splash.setVisible(true);
        }
    });

    USBConnection usbConnection = new USBConnection();
    boolean success = usbConnection.connect();
    if(!success){
        System.err.println("Could not connect to USB device.");
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                splash.setVisible(false);
                splash.dispose();
            }
        });
        return;
    }

    final CFSMainFrame application = new CFSMainFrame(usbConnection);

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            splash.setVisible(false);
            splash.dispose();
            application.pack();
            application.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This is a brilliant idea, and probably the best optimized way of achieving the wanted results. I do however have one concern regarding this, because setting up the USB connection performs some tests on the device which return results and these results are used to decide how the main frame should look. Do you think that might be a problem?

Comment: Whatever you do during initialization the results can be stored as attributes of the USBConnection instance. Because you pass it as a reference to your CFSMainFrame during construction, you can retrieve whatever information you need.

Comment: Ohh yeah. I missed that part. I implemented it and it seems to be working, I do however have a small problem with a NullPointerException that I need to found the source of, but if I fix the problem I will definitively add your answer as THE answer. Thanks! :P